# Convert string with commas and dots to double

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, double

Server returns string in format "123.123". I need to convert it to Double. But in some cultures double is in format "123,123". (Diff is in dot and comma.)

What is the best way to solve this problem? At the end I want to see this code working:

```
var s1 = "123.123";
var s2 = "123,123";

var d1 = Convert.ToDouble(s1);
var d2 = Convert.ToDouble(s2);

if(d1 == d2)
{
    //Problem is solved
}
```

Comment: [`Convert.ToDouble(string, IFormatProvider)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s9ak971(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I know it, what provider should I use? CultureInfo doesnt help me

Comment: The MSDN article I linked shows how to set up the number format info with a complete example at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

`var result = Convert.ToDouble("23.45", (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))` worked for me in different language settings

Comment: it doesn't work with comma as decimal separator. The _InvariantCulture_ **always** uses the dot as decimal separator so it will fail with this number (23,45).